# How to get diff to NOT follow symlinks?

Tags: diff, symlink, symlink-traversal

I'm using `diff` to compare two huge volumes, and it is actually comparing many symlinked files over and over.

Is there some way to stop this? I want it to just compare the link itself; not follow it.

Or is there an alternate app that has this option?

Answer (score 5):

There is an argument --no-dereference which is not mentioned in the man page
but listed by diff --help.

```
diff -r --no-dereference  dir1 dir2
```

Comment: Dammit! `man` pages are the most accessible doc, but over some ideological persnicketing, users have to scrape through `info` pages as well, or look at 3 different sources for help...
Just to say this option is mentionned in the `info diff` as well.